# Haskell: Algebraic types error (Suffix trees: recursion)

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, string-matching, suffix-tree

Working on a function that given a SuffixTree as input, outputs the list of integers in that suffix tree. For example. getIndices tree1 = [2,4,1,3,5,0] . The order of the list of integers does not matter. I am getting the error, on the second last line of the function: "`Couldn't match expected type 'SuffixTree' with actual type '[SuffixTree]'`". I have thought about this for a long time now and have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data SuffixTree = Leaf Int | Node [ ( String, SuffixTree ) ] 
            deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

text1 :: String
text1 = "banana"

tree1 :: SuffixTree
tree1 = Node [("banana",Leaf 0),
              ("a",Node [("",Leaf 5),
                         ("na",Node [("",Leaf 3),
                                     ("na",Leaf 1)])]),
              ("na",Node [("",Leaf 4),
                          ("na",Leaf 2)])]

------------------------------------------------------------------

getIndices :: SuffixTree -> [ Int ]
getIndices sufTree = getIndices' sufTree [] 
  where getIndices' :: SuffixTree -> [Int] -> [Int]
        getIndices' (Node ((_, Node xs):ys)) c 
          | Node xs == Node [] = c
          | otherwise = getIndices' ((Node xs):([Node ys])) c
        getIndices' (Node ((_,Leaf i):xs)) c = getIndices' (Node xs) (i:c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `getIndices'` utility function is declared to take a `SuffixTree`, but in the `otherwise` case you're passing it `(Node xs:[Node ys])` which has type `[SuffixTree]`.

Given that all you want to do is to collect up the integers in the tree, perhaps your `otherwise` case just needs to call `getIndices'` twice:

```
| otherwise = getIndices' (Node xs) (getIndices' (Node ys) c)
```

Your code also has some other problems. If you compile with warnings (`-Wall`) the compiler will warn you about incomplete pattern matches. Your code also fails at runtime because of them.

The incompleteness is because `getIndices'` doesn't cover all possible kinds of `SuffixTree`. You also need to fill in cases for `getIndices' (Leaf Int)` and `getIndices' (Node [])`.

Also, your existing case for `| Node xs == Node []` within the `Node ((_, Node xs):ys` case then becomes redundant: it'll be handled by the recursive call to `getIndices'` from the `otherwise` case and then the new `Node []` case. You might also think about how to simplify the two cases you have already into a single case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realise this, but I don't understand how a 'list of SuffixTree' is possible, after all it is a recursive type and a suffix tree could be a list of suffix trees. Have I got the recursion correct and how could I improve my syntax?

Comment: According to your data definition, you can make a list of SuffixTrees into a SuffixTree using the `Node` constructor and by annotating each one with a `String`. That doesn't mean that a list of SuffixTrees *is* a SuffixTree. I guess the `String` is supposed to indicate which branch to go down - what would you expect `Node xs` and `Node ys` to be annotated with?

Comment: I added a suggestion about how you might make this work better.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about that. I'm not too sure actually?

Comment: I added the extra detail now.

Comment: Using this idea as well an additional line of code namely:

    getIndices' (Node []) c = c

at the end I have managed to get it working, thank you very much for the help it is much appreciated.